# Javascript framework to easily add dynamic/hover effects to website

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, jquery-events

I would like to make a website that has a lot of on-hover effects or effects when you scroll down the page. Like if you look at this page: http://eacykler.dk/ - and then hover on some of the images on the page. I refuse to believe, that someone sat and coded that JavaScript, bit by bit. So I was wondering if some library/framework/gathering/i-don't-know-what-it-should-be-called exists, that makes it easy to implement dynamic effects in HTML/CSS. I imagined something like this:

STATIC VERSION:

```
<div>
<a href="#">
<img src="/foo/bar.jpg" />
</a>
</div>
```

DYNAMIC VERSION:

```
<div class="bg-fades-to-black-in-10-sec">
<a href="#" class="font-color-fades-to-white-in-10-sec">
<img src="/foo/bar.jpg" class="spins-30-degrees-and-zooms-20-percent-in-10-sec" />
</a>
</div>
```

... I hope the class-names illustrates, what the different elements should do. So that instead of having to write JavaScript, then I should just lookup the different functions/options that this given library/framework/gathering/i-don't-know-what-it-should-be-called offers me, and then insert those class-names to get the elements to do it.

Does it exist? If not - then how do I achieve these effects in the fastest and easiest way?

Comment: Google for CSS transitions. Those effects are a one-liner. I'm sure you can even reverse engineer it if you take the time to inspect the DOM.

Comment: There are way more css animation libraries than you can imagine. Here's one that should do what you need: https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/

Comment: I disagree with the closing of this topic. Since someone can come up with an answer (see below), then this shouldn't be closed. I'm not asking for a recommendation of a book, a tool, a library or any such thing. I'm looking for a recommendation of solutions to this - how people would do it. I just formulated the question, so people knew, that I didn't mind, if the solutions was very different.

Comment: I FOUND AN ANSWER MYSELF, in case somebody else find this post. I was looking for something like this: http://www.sequencejs.com/ ... I hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this can all be done using CSS transitions like so:

```
.spins-30-degrees-and-zooms-20-percent-in-10-sec {
    width:100px;
    transform:rotate(0deg);
    transition: all 10s;
}
.spins-30-degrees-and-zooms-20-percent-in-10-sec:hover {
    width:120px;
    transform:rotate(30deg);
}

.font-color-fades-to-white-in-10-sec {
    color:#000;
    transition: all 10s;
}
.font-color-fades-to-white-in-10-sec:hover {
    color:#fff;
}
```

see working fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/pjdz9ohw/1/